# Android BottomSheet with FloatButton

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button, android-support-design

How to make this interaction Bottom sheet and FloatButton like in Google Map?
The first screenshot shows two FloatButtons.After clicking on map, the second button change icon and scroll up and hooking on bottomSheet edge.(Screenshot2).

[First Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHnnT.png)

[Second Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmlXg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that FAB firstly is anchored to the `right|bottom` of the `MapView` and has the same elevation as the `BottomSheet` view.

Once the `BottomSheet` is peeking to some height and `BottomSheet` top is equal to the half of the height of the FAB, then a new anchor id is attached to FAB `CoordinatorLayout.Params`, which basically is the id `BottomSheet` view.

Just to give you code pointers:

```
CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = (CoordinatorLayout.Behavior)fab.getLayoutParams();
int boundary = fab.getTop() + (fab.getHeight() * 0.5);


//inside `BottomSheet` callback methods
if(sheetView.getTop() >= boundary){
   //sheet is expanding or its peeking height was changed
   behavior.setAnchorId(sheetView.getId());
} else if (sheetView.getTop() <= boundary){
   //sheet is animating to collapse, being collapsed 
   behavior.setAnchorId(mapView.getId());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good reference to get you started:

[How to implement BottomSheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618998/how-to-implement-bottom-sheets-using-new-design-support-library-23-2)

[Android Developer Blog on Bottom Sheets](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)

To help you further, please post existing code and what you've tried.