# Disable BottomSheet Drag

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-support-design, bottom-sheet

Due to my low reputation point, I can't comment. So i'm extending this question:
[Disabling User dragging on BottomSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35794264/disabling-user-dragging-on-bottomsheet)

The solution provided by Ray W works but now it expands by sliding and dragging on parent view (CoordinatorLayout).

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnoET.jpg)

In that image, if I drag on "Unwanted Drag Area", BottomSheet slides up. How can I filtered out or stop the touch events on unwanted view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the onInterceptTouchEvent function return value from [Ray W solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36775907/2069361) to this:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(CoordinatorLayout parent, V child, MotionEvent event) {
  return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(parent, child, event) && mAllowUserDragging;
}
```

One more thing, if you have a ListView in BottomSheetLayout, then scrolling items in ListView will change the bottomSheetBehavior state to "STATE_DRAGGING" from "STATE_EXPANDED".
Sample code piece:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {    
        if(isBottomViewOpen){ // set this bool in behavior callback
            behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: in regards to your listview comment.  What's the fix for this?  I have a recyclerview in a bottomsheet and I'm experiencing the same issue.  If I try to drag the bottomsheet anywhere else other than in the recyclerview, the bottomsheet remains expanded as expected.  Only when dragging the recyclerview does the bottomsheet start dragging as well.

Comment: I ended up using this one: https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel
There are lots of other problems in Bottomsheet e.g. not refreshing ListView in BottomSheet. So I quit and use SlidingUpPanel instead.

Answer (score 7):

For the Kotlin, simply add below line in your code,

```
behaviour.isDraggable = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, It solved two problem I had.

1- It block the dragging event.

2- It solves the listView scrolling problem

```
CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<View> behavior;

View profile_config_layout_bottom_sheet = findViewById(R.id.list_view_audience_profile_config_layout);

CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) profile_config_layout_bottom_sheet.getLayoutParams();
behavior = layoutParams.getBehavior();
assert behavior != null;
((BottomSheetBehavior<View>) behavior).addBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
        if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING) {
            ((BottomSheetBehavior<View>) behavior).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        } 
    }
    @Override
    public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {}
});
```

Show the dialog with:

> ((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem.

Answer (score -3):

Look at this :

```
mBottomSheetBehavior1.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING) {
                    mBottomSheetBehavior1.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
                Log.i("BottomSheetCallback", "slideOffset: " + slideOffset);
            }
        });
```

Close BottomSheet when onBackPress :

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mBottomSheetBehavior1.getState() != 4) {
            mBottomSheetBehavior1.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```