# Keep Buttomsheet in collapsible state

Tags: android, android-layout, bottom-sheet

I have a bottom sheet that has inside a `listview`, I don't want to have the behaviour to expand or to dismiss, I just want to keep it at the fixed size, Now it shows at the size I want **(70% of screen)** but on slide up or down it changes its state.
**Is there a way i can do this?**

**I have tried:**

```
      BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback bottomSheetCallback = new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {

                if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
//                    dismiss();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
                bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
            }
        };
//        bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(bottomSheetCallback);
        if (behavior != null && behavior instanceof BottomSheetBehavior) {
            ((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setBottomSheetCallback(bottomSheetCallback);
               ((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setPeekHeight(((RestaurantsActivity) getActivity()).getHeightForFragment());
        }
```

Comment: maybe check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35794264/disabling-user-dragging-on-bottomsheet

Comment: you use modal bottomSheet fragment or Persistent bottom sheets?

Comment: Then why you have chosen to use `BottomSheet`? Is there a special need?