# BottomSheetDialogFragment with Scrollable view

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I have a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` layout with a constraint layout and the constraint layout has a `NumberPicker`. `NumberPicker` scrolls okay, but if the user scrolls outside of the picker, the `BottomSheet` moves which I do not want. How do I stop this.[image]

Basically, when the user drag on the white part, I do not want the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` to be dragged down.

Please let me know if you have the solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Make your scrollable views cover areas until end on left and right side, or put some empty views on those white part which does consume event but do nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling User dragging on BottomSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35794264/disabling-user-dragging-on-bottomsheet)

Comment: @ADM it's completely different.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve a similar UI that has a bottomSheetDialogFragment with a NumberPicker. Could you please point me to some code on how to achieve this?