# NullPointerException with AppCompat BottomSheets

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, material-design, android-appcompat

```
LinearLayout bottomSheetViewgroup = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottomSheet);

bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetViewgroup);

bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED); //this line
```

I have this code within my activity's `onCreate()` method and I'm getting the below NPE exception when the last line is executed:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:
>                Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.ref.WeakReference.get()' on a null object reference 
>                at android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.java:440)

Comment: Have you added `app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"` to your LinearLayout?

Comment: yes, I followed this tutorial http://www.materialdoc.com/bottom-sheets/

Comment: add a NPE check before you call the last line

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While Sanf0rds answer is correct, it doesn't allow the ability to define the BottomSheet as expanded by default. The issue is caused by the WeakReference not being set until the last line of onLayoutChild.

The solution is to provide our own class which extends BottomSheetBehavior, but setting the state inside an overridden onLayoutChild. The code is provided below.

uk/ac/qub/quibe/misc/ExpandedBottomSheetBehavior.java

```
package uk.ac.qub.quibe.misc;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by mcp on 15/03/16.
 */
public class ExpandedBottomSheetBehavior<V extends View> extends android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior<V> {

    public ExpandedBottomSheetBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLayoutChild(final CoordinatorLayout parent, final V child, final int layoutDirection) {
        SavedState dummySavedState = new SavedState(super.onSaveInstanceState(parent, child), STATE_EXPANDED);
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(parent, child, dummySavedState);
        return super.onLayoutChild(parent, child, layoutDirection);
        /*
            Unfortunately its not good enough to just call setState(STATE_EXPANDED); after super.onLayoutChild
            The reason is that an animation plays after calling setState. This can cause some graphical issues with other layouts
            Instead we need to use setInternalState, however this is a private method.
            The trick is to utilise onRestoreInstance to call setInternalState immediately and indirectly
         */
    }

}
```

In the layout file reference reference your new custom behavior.

Change

```
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
```

To

```
app:layout_behavior="uk.ac.qub.quibe.misc.ExpandedBottomSheetBehavior"
```

Comment: Nice that worked perfectly. 
*Very* ingenuous! You should also mention that you need to cast the object returned by `from()`. Something like - `bottomSheetBehavior = (HiddenBottomSheetBehavior) HiddenBottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);`

Comment: @guy why does casting it matter?

Comment: Great solution! If  (like me) you are making changes to the view as it opens and closes, you will need to set a flag in the overridden behavior class and perform the dummy save/restore of the state only on the first time through. Otherwise the drawer will keep resetting back to the initial state defined here.

Comment: I added condition around this
SavedState dummySavedState = new SavedState(super.onSaveInstanceState(parent, child), STATE_EXPANDED);
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(parent, child, dummySavedState);

so it will only happen once

Comment: Working like a charm, thanks a lot! Great solution with condition to save/restore state once.

Answer (score 5):

```
public class ExpandedBottomSheetBehavior<V extends View> extends
    android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior<V> {

  public ExpandedBottomSheetBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

  @Override
  public boolean onLayoutChild(final CoordinatorLayout parent, final V child, final int layoutDirection) {
    return super.onLayoutChild(parent, child, layoutDirection);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(CoordinatorLayout parent, V child, MotionEvent event) {
    try {
      return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(parent, child, event);
    } catch (NullPointerException ignored) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: solved it after adding onInterceptTouchEvent method.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your code is you are trying to call the setState method directly inside onCreate. This is will throw a nullPointer because the WeakReference is not initialized yet. It will get initialized when the Coordinator layout is about to lay its child view.

> onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout parent, V child, int layoutDirection)
>
> Called when the parent CoordinatorLayout is about the lay out the
>   given child view.

So the best approach is set the peek height to 0 and show/hide inside the onItemClick listener.

I have answered this question here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36236743/1314796

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution but I still don't known why this happen. The solution is put this last line to user call directly after the activity is running. Ex: in a contextMenu callback or in any OnClickListener.

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider listening to the global layout event, this way you'll be sure that the bottomsheet has been laid out when setting the collapsed state.

```
final View bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
bottomSheet.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            bottomSheet.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
            bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(300);
            bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Tried this but all I get is 

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewTreeObserver android.view.View.getViewTreeObserver()' on a null object reference
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewTreeObserver android.view.View.getViewTreeObserver()' on a null object reference