# Android bottom sheet crash after update support library

Tags: android, android-support-library, bottom-sheet

We have a bottom sheet, after updating support library version  to '26.0.1', when you open the app and before bottom sheet is shown, the app is crashed.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/vf_ovelay_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="32dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
            app:behavior_skipCollapsed="true"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and

```
private BottomSheetBehavior mBottomSheetBehavior;
private ViewGroup bottomSheet;
```

and here is how I show it

```
mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
mBottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(true);//Important to add
        mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
bottomSheet.removeAllViews();
bottomSheet.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
bottomSheet.addView(getCustomView());
```

When I click on the screen, the app crashes!

and the log is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.ref.WeakReference.get()' on a null object reference
at android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior.onInterceptTouchEvent(BottomSheetBehavior.java:299)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.performIntercept(CoordinatorLayout.java:460)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onInterceptTouchEvent(CoordinatorLayout.java:499)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2310)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2371)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2371)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2371)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2371)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2371)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2371)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2568)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1776)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2866)
```

Comment: please add log here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906125/nullpointerexeption-with-appcompat-bottomsheets Check this it may help you

Comment: Did you find a solution? Same problem here

Comment: same too. Would be helpful if you updated this thread (this is the first one that comes in google)

Comment: This was only solved by creating custom BottomSheetBehavior class and update the onInterceptTouchEvent method.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was only solved by creating custom `BottomSheetBehavior` class and update the `onInterceptTouchEvent` method.

more info: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior

https://github.com/google/ground-android/blob/master/gnd/src/main/java/com/google/android/gnd/ui/common/BottomSheetBehavior.java

Don't forget to migrate it to AndroidX: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate