# How to disable BottomSheetDialogFragment dragging

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-dialog, bottom-sheet

How to disable `BottomSheetDialogFragment` dragging by finger?

I saw similar questions, but they're all about `BottomSheet` not `BottomSheetDialogFragment`.

Comment: Take a look at this explanation @Виталий Обидейко here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39892726/4394827

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Having created `MyActivity` as follows:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        new MyBottomSheetFragment().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "tag");
    }

    public static class MyBottomSheetFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

        @Override
        public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
            BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog;
            bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(R.layout.sample);

            try {
                Field behaviorField = bottomSheetDialog.getClass().getDeclaredField("behavior");
                behaviorField.setAccessible(true);
                final BottomSheetBehavior behavior = (BottomSheetBehavior) behaviorField.get(bottomSheetDialog);
                behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                        if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING{ 
                            behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
                    }
                });
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where `R.layout.sample` is a simple layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#e479da" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#798de4" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#e4db79" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You'll get following output:

[image]

<sup>A part of solution is borrowed from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35794743/1083957) answer.</sup>

Comment: This is good sample code, but there are some issues.
First, setupDialog isn't the BottomSheetDialogFragment method.
Second, I have a recycler view in my bottom sheet view, and when I drag bottom sheet from recyclerView's blank spaces bottom sheet slides down.

Comment: [`setupDialog()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/fragment/src/main/java/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.java#324) is a method from `DialogFragment` class. Have substituted it with `onCreateDialog()`. Cannot understand your use case. Can you post a simple project at github with that behavior?

Comment: it's getting warning in my fragment: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field mBehavior in class 
    Landroid/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialog; (declaration of 
   'android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetDialog' )
System.err:     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Native Method)

Comment: The field's name is behavior, no mBehavior. That's why you are getting that error.

Comment: Thanks, @MarcoCarrizales, updated answer from `mBehavior` to `behavior`.

Comment: I also changed the code to be in setupDialog() instead of onCreateDialog()

Comment: @sagarsuri I just posted the Kotlin version with data binding of this answer. I hope you find it useful.

Comment: Answer by @jakubbialkowski below is better in my opinion.

Answer (score 43):

There is simpler way of achieving the same after material design 1.2.0 was released.

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetBehavior#setdraggable

When calling from `BottomSheetDialogFragment`:

```kotlin
    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val bottomSheetDialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState) as BottomSheetDialog
        bottomSheetDialog.setOnShowListener {
            val bottomSheet = bottomSheetDialog
                .findViewById<FrameLayout>(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet)

            if (bottomSheet != null) {
                val behavior: BottomSheetBehavior<*> = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet)
                behavior.isDraggable = false
            }
        }
        return bottomSheetDialog
    }
```

Or with styling:

```xml
    <style name="SomeStyle" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="behavior_draggable">false</item>
    </style>
```

And then in `onCreate` of your dialog fragment:

```kotlin
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.SomeStyle)
    }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer and should have way more up votes!

Comment: Using the styling is way better than the other answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

Too late but worth to share.

```
  behavior.setDraggable(false)
```

This line did the job.

Comment: what class has isDraggable?

Comment: `final BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618998/how-to-implement-bottom-sheets-using-new-design-support-library-23-2/35620244

Comment: @AndreyUglev it comes from `BottomSheetDialog.behavior`.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  This method was added in a new version of the material library.  I am using `com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0` and I have the `setDraggable()` method.  I did not have the method when I was on version `1.1.0`.  It is in the documentation as well... https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetBehavior#setDraggable(boolean)

Answer (score 13):

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    //Disable dragging by set isDraggable to false
    val bottomSheetDialog = dialog as BottomSheetDialog
    val bottomSheetBehavior = bottomSheetDialog.behavior
    bottomSheetBehavior.isDraggable = false
}
```

Comment: isDraggable in Kotlin. if you use Java use setDraggable(boolean draggable)

Answer (score 9):

If you want to disable `BottomSheetDialog` dragging, try to set `setCancelable(false)`.

Comment: it works in my case, just had a problem where clicking on the outside field would become disabled after setting cancelable to false. thanks. +1

Comment: Not working. ...

Answer (score 7):

My version. It works perfectly.

**Edit 09/04/2020:** Replaced depreciated `setBottomSheetCallback()` with `addBottomSheetCallback()`

```kotlin
class FragMenuBDrawer : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    ...

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState) as BottomSheetDialog

        dialog.setOnShowListener {
            val bottomSheet = (it as BottomSheetDialog).findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet) as FrameLayout?
            val behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet!!)
            behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED

            behavior.addBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
                override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
                    if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING) {
                        behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
                    }
                }

                override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {}
            })
        }

        // Do something with your dialog like setContentView() or whatever
        return dialog
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In your `oncreateView`

```
//Kotlin
val baseDialog = dialog
if (baseDialog is BottomSheetDialog) {
    baseDialog.behavior.isDraggable = false
}
//If cancelable also not required.
isCancelable = false
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the Kotlin version of [azizbekian's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46861306/how-to-disable-bottomsheetdialogfragment-dragging/47616374#47616374) answer since someone asked about using data binding

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
override fun setupDialog(d: Dialog?, style: Int) {
    super.setupDialog(d, style)
    dialogExampleBinding = DataBindingUtil
        .inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), R.layout.dialogExample, null, false) //This is for data binding only
    d?.setContentView(R.layout.dialogExample)

    val myDialog:BottomSheetDialog = d as BottomSheetDialog
    val dField = myDialog.javaClass.getDeclaredField("behavior") //This is the correct name of the variable in the BottomSheetDialog class
    dField.isAccessible = true
    val behavior = dField.get(d) as BottomSheetBehavior<*>
    behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING) {
                behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
            }
        }

        override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {}
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Just Add** `bottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(false);`

You can get Object of `BottomSheetBehaviour` in `BottomSheetDialogFragment`.

```
 CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) ((View) view.getParent()).getLayoutParams();
            CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = params.getBehavior();
            View parent = (View) view.getParent();
            getHeight(view);
            ((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setFitToContents(true);
            BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(parent);
bottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(false);
```

Comment: And how can we get bottomSheetBehavior object?

Comment: please check answer

Answer (score 2):

This works for me sir

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState : Bundle?) : Dialog {
    val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.setOnShowListener {
        val bottomSheetDialog : BottomSheetDialog = it as BottomSheetDialog;
        var bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior<FrameLayout>();
        bottomSheetBehavior = bottomSheetDialog.getBehavior()
        bottomSheetBehavior.setDraggable(false);
    }
    return dialog }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I managed to fix it:

```
mBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from((View) rootView.getParent());
mBehavior.setHideable(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Top rated answer contains boilerplate code such as Field and try-catches.

So here is a better version of it in Kotlin:

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState).apply {
        setOnShowListener(::onShow)
    }
}

private fun onShow(dialogInterface: DialogInterface) {
    val dialog = dialogInterface as BottomSheetDialog
    val frameLayout =
        dialog.findViewById<FrameLayout>(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet)
            ?: return

    BottomSheetBehavior.from(frameLayout).apply {
        addBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
                if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING)
                    state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
            }

            override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) = Unit
        })
    }
}
```

Use it in `BottomSheetDialogFragment`

Answer (score 0):

I get the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48362662/11445944), I just added `content.setLayoutParams(new CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));`
 to make Bottom Sheet Dialog Fragment height is match_parent and make it soft when it showed.

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Dialog d = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    // view hierarchy is inflated after dialog is shown
    d.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            //this disables outside touch
            d.getWindow().findViewById(R.id.touch_outside).setOnClickListener(null);
            //this prevents dragging behavior
            View content = d.getWindow().findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
            content.setLayoutParams(new CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) content.getLayoutParams()).setBehavior(null);
        }
    });
    return d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution

```
    CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<View> behavior;

    View profile_config_layout_bottom_sheet = findViewById(R.id.list_view_audience_profile_config_layout);

    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) profile_config_layout_bottom_sheet.getLayoutParams();
    behavior = layoutParams.getBehavior();
    assert behavior != null;
    ((BottomSheetBehavior<View>) behavior).addBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING) {
                ((BottomSheetBehavior<View>) behavior).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
            } 
        }
        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
setOnShowListener {
            Handler().post {
                val bottomSheet = findViewById<View>(R.id.design_bottom_sheet) as? FrameLayout
                bottomSheet?.let {
                    BottomSheetBehavior.from(it).state = STATE_EXPANDED

                    // Disable dialog dragging behavior which causes issue on EditText scroll!
                    BottomSheetBehavior.from(it).isDraggable = false
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

my simple solution:

```
 override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val dialog = BottomSheetDialog(requireContext(), R.style.DialogRoundedCornerStyle)
    dialog.behavior.apply {
        state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
        isDraggable = false
    }
    return dialog
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They can also do this by setting up draggable, so here's another example of mine.

My BottomSheetDialogFragment contains a RecyclerView inside, if you need a BottomSheetDialogFragment banned drag up, can drag down, What I did is I set the RecyclerView to an absolute height

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="367dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just disable the dismissing of bottomsheet, you can simply set isCancelable false to fragment instance

`val bSheet = BottomSheetFragment.newInstance("") bSheet.isCancelable = false bSheet.show(supportFragmentManager, "sheet")`